# Can we find a real number $a>0$ such that $f(t)>a>0$ and $a$ does not depend of the value of $t$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a strictly positive real function defined on the interval $(0,1)$. Let $t∈(0,1)$ be **fixed**.

Can we find a real number $a>0$ such that $f(t)>a>0$ and $a$ **does not depend of the value of** $t$.

Comment: What if $f(x)=x$?

Comment: @saulspatz: No problem if one $x=t$ is fixed.

Comment: Then I don't understand the second sentence in your question.  What is $a$ if $f(x)=x$?

Comment: @saulspatz: It is any number less than the fixed $x$.

Comment: And you say that it doesn't depend on $x$?  Let's be specific.  If $x = \frac34$, we can take $a=\frac12$, but if $x=\frac12$ we cannot take $a=\frac12$.  I can't understand what you are saying.

Comment: It depends on $f$.  If $\inf f(t) > 0$ then, of course.  If $\inf f(t) = 0$ then, of course not.

Comment: ... but what is the point of saying $t$ is fixed in the first paragraph?  If $t$ is fixed then there will always be an $a_t>0$ so that $f(t) > a_t> 0$ where $a$ *is* dependent on $t$.  Is there any reason why that is not an acceptable condition?

Comment: @fleablood: This is required to solve a certain inequality.

Comment: Then it isn't clear precisely what you are asking. Asking for any that is *independent* of the *fixed* $t$ simply makes no sense and I can't see why it is even being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t$ *is fixed* as you say, the existence of a function $f$ defined on $(0,1)$ is irrelevant, and the requirement "does not depend on the value of $t$" is vacuous. All we have is that the real number

$$f(t)$$

is positive and obviously there is an $a$ such that

$$f(t)>a>0.$$

---

Anyway, $a$ must depend on the value of $f(t)$, for example as $a=\dfrac{f(t)}2$. You can't pick a suitable value for $a$ without knowing $f(t)$, because $\mathbb R_+^*$ has no minimum.

Comment: I am asking about the mathematical justification of the existence of $a$.

Comment: "I am asking about the mathematical justification of the existence of a."  Your question isn't clear.  The existence of an $a$ that is *dependent* on $t$ is justified as $f(t) > 0$.  But the existence of an $a$ that is *independent*, i.e. the existence of an $a$ so that $f(t) > a> 0$ for *all* $t$, is not justified.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Since in the question, you require $a$ **does not depend of the value of** $t$, we may reform the question as:

//

Let $f$ be a strictly positive real function defined on the interval $(0,1)$. Does $\exists \ a > 0 \ $ such that  $f(t)>a>0 \quad \forall \ t∈(0,1) \ $?

//

To see why the answer is no, pick any positive function $\ f(t) \ $ whose $\ range\ $ has *$\ infimum$ $\ 0\ $ in the interval $\ (0,1).\ $ Your question asks if $\ \exists \ $ a single number $\ a>0\ $ that "works" for every value of $t.\ $ But by the definition of infimum, and the fact that the infimum of the range of $\ f(t) $ is $\ 0, \ $ it follows that $ \exists t \in (0,1) $ such that $0<f(t)<a$, contradicting the condition of $a$ in the question.

If, however, the original question was:

//

Let $f$ be a strictly positive real function defined on the interval $(0,1)$ and whose range has $ \ infimum \ c>0\ $ .Does $\exists \ a > 0 \ $ such that, $\forall t∈(0,1), \ $ $f(t)>a>0$?

//

$Then $ the answer would be yes: choose $a = \frac{1}{2} \ inf \left\{f(x): x \in (0,1) \right\} $.

*For a definition of $infimum$, see Rudin's PMA Definition 1.8. Also, OP, I recommend you get this book if you don't already have it, as you ask a lot of questions on limits and functions etc, and it's a good book for thinking through rigorous definitions of real numbers, functions, sequences and series, limits, continuity etc.

Comment: I just found a free version of Rudin’s PMA at the top of a google search :O

Answer (score -1):

There is no such $a$. Fix $t \in (0,1)$ and imagine that there is some constant $a$ that doesn't depend on $t$ such that 
$$f(t)> a > 0.$$

Since $a$ doesn't depend on $t$ we must have $f(t') > a > 0$ for any other $t' \in (0,1).$

Now consider any function which is strictly positive such that $f(t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$ (e.g. $f(x) = x$ on $(0,1)$) then taking the limit as $t \rightarrow 0$ in 
$$ f(t) > a > 0$$
gives us 
$ 0 \geq a \geq 0.$ Therefore $a = 0$ which contradicts the fact that $a > 0.$

Comment: $f$ is a strictly positive real function

Comment: @Helena. It is easy to find strictly positive functions $f(t)$ which tend to 0 as $t\to0$. For example $f(t)=t$.

Comment: @Helena I've edited my answer. I hope it clarifies any misunderstandings you had.